# What do I need to learn in order to really understand Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I've graduated with a math major in undergrad, but mostly focused on algebra (Galois Theory, Knot theory, etc.). I work in something unrelated right now, but now I want to study machine learning. The question is, what kind of knowledge should I have if I want to *really* understand machine learning?

Say, here are some things I can think of, but obviously I'm missing a lot, I'm assuming.

- "Fundamentals" (Calculus, Linear Algebra, Discrete Mathematics, Coding, etc.)
- Probability (but what specific areas?)
- Statistics (but what kind?)
- Algorithms
- Differential Equations

But what else? Or what subfields of what I've mentioned above are particularly important (i.e. Bayesian statistics)?

Edit: I am currently considering a graduate program in ML, and wanted to know if this is something I really want to do / know more about it / prepare myself.

Comment: This depends on what kind of work you want to do with ML, you could just use libraries and barely touch maths at all, or you could learn lots of maths and create whole new algorithms of your own. Depends on what you'd enjoy doing more.

Comment: @Tasty213 I've been using ML libraries, and I wanted to learn a lot of math and really get into the nitty-gritty of ML. I understand it'll be a long process, but something I want to do.

Comment: Have you considered a postgrad in ML/AI, you get basically an entire year to study whatever your thesis is on and could really learn what you want. Before actually implementing it proving your capable to employers.

Comment: read the book „Introduction to Statistical Learning“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From somebody with a PhD in Probability working with AI/ML for a living. Basics of Probability theory, maybe wikipedia/cousera/... for the very basics if you never had a class in it, followed by e.g. “Probability with Martingales” by Williams.
The papers [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_computer_science#Machine_learning) will also give you a good feel.

As for books, [this](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/copy.html.) one on “classical” machine learning is pretty good and free For Deep Learning https://www.deeplearningbook.org/, this one also has the basics of probability theory.

For reinforcement learning http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html.
For the applied side, slides from https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/ and http://cs231n.stanford.edu/.

As for statistics don’t bother, I’ve never seen any machine learning work reference a theorem in “pure” statistics, if there is such a thing.
Of course standard undergraduate calculus and linear algebra. And learn some Python while you’re at it

Comment: What do you mean by "pure statistics"? Statistics involving probability theory(measures, etc.)? 
Because it's very easy to find statistical concepts in machine learning. Here's one: Cross Validation. Here's another: Model Estimation/Fitting/Selection. There's a bunch of them.

Comment: I meant not to get sidetracked in stuff like Bayesian Decision Theory, become an expert in computing with exponential families or spend a lot of time learning a zoo of statistical tests and models and the conditions under which they apply. Also statistics tends to have a lot of domain-specific terminology for things that are just simple applications of probability theory. For machine learning it tends to be enough to know the underlying probability and measure theory, whereas if you were to work say with clinical trials you would probably need to know more of the stuff I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better to start with some specialization in ml for example on coursera in oder to find interesting fields for you. There are different levels of complexity and extra knowledge isn't necessary in part of them. One more advantage is that you will have useful recommendation about materials. Then you can deepen in some area of researches and understand what you need to learn in addition. I would suggest courses by *Andrew Ng*.

Speaking about algorithm, "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth is a good choice to have strong background in basiс algorithms, if you want in future to work on the development of ml methods by your self.

Bayesian methods could be an extra field of study, it's interesting area, but it doesn't mean, that you will need it in every possible ml research )

Comment: Isn't the art of computer programming meant to be insanely complicated and only really necessary for programming language design?

Comment: @Tasty213 you're right. This book will be good just if the author is interested in ml engineering. I've added this notice.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning is mostly(if not all about) function approximations and besides what you've already sad in order to do that you have to understand fields like inferential statistics, information theory(look for Kullback–Leibler divergence, mutual information), which in turn require knowledge in probability distributions(gaussian distribution) and bayesian probability(conditional probability). Also, when thinking about techniques of dimensionality reduction and clusterization, most of them are all about linear algebra(decomposition methods like eigendecomposition and singular value decomposition).

Comment: what are common applications of information theory in machine learning?